Question about how straddle bets change the hand
We are playing 10/20 limit holdem.
6 players (named A, B, C, D, E and F) at the table.
Using the following symbols to illustrate:
* = button
S = small blind
B = big blind
X = straddler

Here is our table, with player B on the button. Player E places a straddle bet before the cards are dealt.
   *  S  B  X
A  B  C  D  E  F

Normally, the big blind (player D) would be the last player to bet in each round of the hand. But since player E placed a straddle bet, player F is first to bet after the cards are dealt and player E is last to bet. Does that betting order continue throughout all subsequent betting rounds, or does it only apply to the first betting round? In other words, would player F be first to bet in all betting rounds because player E placed a straddle bet before the cards were dealt?
I'm also wondering about bets and raises. After player E places a straddle, it means our 10/20 limit holdem game will require a pre-flop call of 20 in order to stay in the hand. If someone wants to raise pre-flop, the raise amount would be 20. Does that effectively change the entire hand to a 20/40 hand? For example, would the last two rounds of betting require bets and raises of 40?

This depends on where you play.
In my dealing experience, Player E is not the last to bet. They were first to bet in the hand, and have already done so. It's their decision to do so blindly.
If all other players match their straddle, that's the action complete, pot merged, burn and reveal. Player E does not get to make a further bet as if they are the big(ger) blind because that's just not how poker with blinds works.
If you decide to allow straddles to effectively purchase the big blind at the cost of raising stakes pre-flop, well, that's exactly what you've chosen and that's exactly what it will do. Even I  games where this rule is applied, it does not totally alter the table limits; you are still a 10/20 table regardless of the straddle, that is the requirement of the following rounds.


If all other players match their straddle, that's the action complete, pot merged, burn and reveal. Player E does not get to make a further bet as if they are the big(ger) blind because that's just not how poker with blinds works.

Then what's the incentive of the straddle?

Fun, usually. Unpredictability,  maybe. Why does there need to be an incentive for something to be an option? It's a bad option in terms of expected value profits, but so is playing poker at all for the majority of players.

@AndrewChin After I did some further reading, it sounds like each poker room has their own rules for straddles. There are indeed some rooms where Player E would get to bet make a further bet and would be last to bet in a round for that hand. That, in my opinion, is the only incentive for a straddle. The straddler would be taking the risk of a blind raise and the benefit of doing it would be that they bet last. It's a risk/reward thing. If you didn't get to bet last, it would always be a bad idea because you'd make a blind raise and still have to bet first.

There is a difference between a straddle and blind raise. If your poker room allows players to straddle then they are last to act pre-flop and can re-raise if there are callers or raisers of the straddle. The straddle is, in effect, a third blind. After the flop the normal action order is in effect. The small blind is first to act, big blind second, and then the straddler.
Straddles will always be double the big blind, so 40 in your example of a 10/20 game. Subsequent players will need to match this bet of 40 in order to call.
Some card rooms don't allow people to straddle, but they should be able to blind raise before they are dealt cards. If everyone just calls their blind raise they do not have the option to raise, as they would if they could straddle.

The big blind in a 10/20 LHE game is 10, which would make the straddle 20.
